# Does CSS Shorthand Exist?

Tags: css, shorthand

Is there a shorthand for selecting all occurrences of these elements within the specified div?  These elements appear many different levels deep in the markup.

```
    div.op-custom-html-block h1,
    div.op-custom-html-block h2,
    div.op-custom-html-block p {
        font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    }
```

Comment: a shorthand for what ?? doesn't your code what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't a way for that in CSS. If you want a feature like this you have to use a pre-processor like Sass.